# Whats the Quickest and Cheapest Solution to setup a Affiliate Program for an Online Product?

Tags: affiliate

I have a simple HTML landing page setup for an online product I want to sell. This product is a hardcover book. I want to be able to allow other people to setup their own landing pages and make a percentage of the sale from their site. What are some good payment processors or payment gateways that make setting up an affiliate system easy and fast?

Clarification - When someone purchases an item, I want (whatever the payment processor is) to automatically route a percentage of that payment to the affiliate and the rest to the original author.) Are there any payment frameworks that already do this?

I've found a few sites that let you do this, but they seem to restrict you to digital purchases only. However, my sites is selling a ship-able product and the affiliate system needs to support this.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an affiliate network such as Webgains. Affiliates sign up to your program through the Webgains interface and you can choose whether to accept or decline them. You set a percentage of commission which is then automatically paid, Webgains track the sales made and compiles a spreadsheet so you can check everything is working properly and decline any transactions that have been cancelled or refunded so you're not paying commission for items that haven't actually been sold. It's no problem to set up for ship-able products.

I have used before and it's very simple to use and Webgains have integration managers who can help you to set everything up.